# PHP Check complicated String for correct format

Tags: php, regex, string, formatting

Looking for some help on how to validate a string in PHP.

The format to validate against is

```
X.XXam[d[i]-d[i] Only]
```

A sample entry could be:

```
8:55pm[Tues-Thurs Only]
```

`d[i]` represents an associative array value depending on the day of the week.
For instance, the above contains Saturday and Sunday.

I need to make sure/validate this before inserting in the DB.

Can I get some help with this?

Comment: Please could you show `d[i]` content and your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out regex 101. It is a wonderfull Tool to create regular expressions and understand them. From there i got [this solution](http://regex101.com/r/sW8bZ0) for you:

```
%^\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}([ap])m\[(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|-){1,} Only\]$%mg
```

The first bit (`\d{1,2}`) accepts a number between 0 and 99, then a `:` and another number between 0 and 99.
Then it is either `a` or `p` followed by `m`.
Then you have either `Mon` or `Tue` or .... or `-` for 1 to endles times.

At the end you have the modifiers `g` and `m`. 
The `m` is to make use of the `^` and `$` modifiers that represent the beginning and the end of a line.
The `g` is just to find ALL results rather than the first existing. You can leave that out.

To use Weekdays from an array called `$array` simply implode it to a string and fill it into your expression like this:

```
$weekdaysString = implode('|',$array);
$regex = '%^\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}([ap])m\[('.$weekdaysString.'|-){1,} Only\]$%mg';
```

Read up on [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: Is there a way to return the weekday value that was selected? Or it's key?

Comment: You mean you do not only want to validate but also want to extract the Weekdays contained in the string?

Comment: yes, exactly. The values in the array are like `$daysArray=array("Monday"=>"Mon","Tuesday"=>"Tues","Wednesday"=>"Wed","Thursday"=>"Thurs","Friday"=>"Fri","Saturday"=>"Sat","Sunday"=>"Sun");`

Comment: @difyzz Just ask another question, providing your input variables as PHP and your desired output/outcome. Another possibility would be to actually use the PHP preg_match_all function and regex101 and find the solution yourself. You can do it! http://regex101.com/

Comment: @difyzz since i just saw your other questions: What you really should do is first evaluate your string and then strip the weekdays according to your allowed patterns which seem to have more options than just "Only" right?

Comment: i don't really get you

Comment: @difyzz You have three questions that all could be resolved with a few simple lines of code that could be written by you if you'd take the time to read the documentation and use the suggested tools. That's what i am saying.

Comment: @AndreschSerj: The g modifier doesn't exist in PHP, the global (or not) research is determined only by the function you use (preg_match vs preg_match_all), or the limit parameter you give (preg_replace, preg_replace_callback, preg_split).

Answer (score 1):

this should work for your case :

```
^\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m\[\w+\-\w+ Only]$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/mH9lX1

Comment: `.` currently matches *any* character. You need to escape it with a backslas to match a literal dot: `\.`. Also, I don't think the OP's format is quite like this. See demo: http://regex101.com/r/wV1hA1

Comment: @AmalMurali i did that deliberately to  match `:`, nyways i ll change it

Comment: Can I use array values to replace the days? That is, $array[0] for Monday and $array[1] for Tuesday. Instead of writing, Mon, Tue, etc.

Comment: the above regex will match anything of the format that you have provided, be it `Mon-Tue` or `Monday-Tuesday` see the `\w+` which stands for one or more word chaaracter